# Which is the best method to fix conflicts ? Rebase or Merge?

Tags: git, github

Have a question regarding two scenarios: We are all working on a repo. Usually I’m working on my own folder, so everything I do is ok. But what if I’m working on a change in a file but the other developer work in the file at the same time?

I checkout a local branch
The other developer checkout another local branch
The other developer commits, push, and merge the code into remote master
I commits, push, and merge the code into remote master. But this will fail because the conflict
What’s the best way to resolve it? Rebase or Merge conflict? How do we merge conflict from github website?

Comment: (Anything in the docs?)

Answer (score 1):

Conflict is not a fail when using Github. git is saying 'hey I'll do everything, just let me know what is right when two of you write different code at the same file at the same time'

There are several tools that helps you merge when conflict happens. (ex. Github Desktop connects to Visual Studio Code to find where conflict is and decide which code to commit)

Then, you can check file as conflict solved then commit it.